# Type error when using onMutate in react query (Optimistic Updates)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query, optimistic

```
export const usePostApi = () =>
  useMutation(['key'], (data: FormData) => api.postFilesImages({ requestBody: data }));
```

Query Definition

```
const { mutateAsync } = usePostApi();

  const {data} = await mutateAsync(formData, {
      onMutate: () => {},
    });
```

component

After defining the query in one place, it is called and used in the component. When calling mutateAsync from a component, an option is provided as the second argument, but if onMutate is put, the following type error occurs. Any idea how to solve it?

**error message:**
Argument of type '{ onMutate: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutateOptions<ResponseData, unknown, FormData, unknown>'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onMutate' does not exist in type 'MutateOptions<ResponseData, unknown, FormData, unknown>'.

Comment: Add more code about `mutateAsync` in your hook.

Answer (score 0):

`onMutate` only exists on the options that you pass to `useMutation`, not the ones that you pass to `mutate`. So if you want to use `onMutate`, you need:

```
export const usePostApi = () =>
  useMutation(
    ['key'],
    (data: FormData) => api.postFilesImages({ requestBody: data }),
    {
        onMutate: () => ...
    }
);
```

Comment: Why React Query not allow `onMutate` option in `mutate` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle Optimistic Updates with mutateAsync:

```
try {
   // handle optimistic updates here, it's similar to `onMutate`;

   await mutateAsync(data);

   // similar to `onSuccess`
}
catch (err) {
   // similar to `onError`;
}
```